# Unable to use openFileInput in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Im new to coding and Im trying to learn it on my own but I have run into the problem in the app I am developing of being unable to use openFileInput in a broadcast reciever. Here is the code:

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



}
```

//end of read froms

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

TextView text;
Button btn;

DateFormat formate = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
Calendar calender2 = Calendar.getInstance();
TextView txt2;
Button btn2;
```

//read froms start

```
private String readFromFilename() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("config.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

If anyone can help i would appreciate any tips or work arounds. The exact error it gives is that it cannot resolve the method. When I tried to research it on my own they mentioned something about context but I couldnt find an example of it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`openFileInput()` is a method on `Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29). You will notice that the second parameter to `onReceive()` is a `Context`. Hence, you can call `openFileInput()` on that `Context` object.

That being said, please note that `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread, and doing disk I/O on the main application thread is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks but what would I have to do to make the openFileInput work in there? I need it in order to send a message using the persons set name.

Comment: @ThomasHolland: "what would I have to do to make the openFileInput work in there?" -- pass in a `Context` as a parameter to `readFromFilename()`. Since you have not shown where or how you are using `readFromFilename()`, it would be difficult to help you further.

Comment: The readFromFilename is being used to access the file config.txt which will return the name in the file. So after the openFileInput is no longer registered as an error ill set up a variable String name=readFromFilename();  . Does that help?

Comment: if doing disk I/o on the main application thread is a bad idea is their a better method you would recommend?

Comment: @ThomasHolland: Well, if we assume that `AlarmReceiver` means that you are using this with `AlarmManager`, use a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead of a `BroadcastReceiver`, and put your business logic in an `IntentService` started by that receiver. See [the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) for details. This addresses your threading (`onHandleIntent()` of the `IntentService` is invoked on a background thread), and it ensures that the device will stay awake while you are doing this work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm all set now.